# C# не может найти SceneManager

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

У меня проблема: Unity или C# (я не шарю) не может найти `SceneManager`. Unity говорит что невозможно найти `SceneManager`, в интернете было что-то но оно мне не помогло. Тем более там упоминался `SceneManagement`, что совсем сбило с толку. Версия Unity которую я использую `LTS 2020.3.14f1`. Ошибка в этом фрагменте кода в if:

```cs
 if (this.CompareTag("Player") && other.CompareTag("Finish"))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManagement.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
    }
```

Игру я делаю по YouTube видео, у автора всё работало

Comment: Текст ошибки какой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте:

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
```